# connection and cursor in the same class in a DBAPI 2.0 implementation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cursor, python-db-api

I have a basic Python interface to a database, where what would be the "connection" class does the querying and retrieveing as well.

I was wondering whether it would make sense to write a dummy `cursor()` function inside that class as:

```
def cursor(self):
    return self
```

and then just implement `fetch()` et al. in the same class.

If it makes a difference, the goal is to connect the database with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I guess the answer might possibly be probably yes (or no), except how'd you handle SQLA or the like calling `close()` on your "cursor", which is actually your connection object. What about multiple  concurrent cursors?

Comment: I initially figured I'd use a local variable like `is_cur_open` to track "closing".  Second question - I guess that would've called for opening another connection instance, as there is no cursor concurrency really